# How does jQuery UI create its exact-copy absolutely positioned drag-helper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to build something where I need an exact copy of any element floated directly over the top of the original element.

The element could be complex and contain any dom elements (in the same way jQuery UI draggable elements can be).

How does jQuery UI create it's absolutely positioned floating helper that's an exact duplicate of the original element? It is initially positioned perfectly over the original element in all cases. The first step would be to clone() the element, but after this, how to you ensure the element looks identical when placed back into the DOM?

For example, if you clone an element that has a percentage width, and then append this on to the body of the document, the width of the document may be larger than the element it was originally parented to. There's lots of other factors to consider to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first step would be to clone() the element

Its absolutely true, and you can easily check how its done simply inspect the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/ui.draggable.js?r=3103)

start finding **_mouseStart: function(event) {**